# Android: remove title bar error

Tags: java, android, titlebar

Hello i'm trying to remove the title bar from my app with this code:

```
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Under the onCreate method in the activity, but when i run the app it gives error and it closes (i'm sorry but i don't know how to see the error log).

Why it gives error? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `setContentView()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(
    final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}
```

If you want to remove the title, just add this style into your manifest file.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `setContentView()`

like:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to do this:

1. Simply you must use `Activity` instead of `Appcompactactivity`.

**Or**

2. Add `getActionBar.hide()` instead of `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` if you use `Appcompactactivity`

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

Write this lines before setcontentview your activity will be full screen

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution  1.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
               getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

Solution 2.

Maybe the problem is due to your app theme. So check your activity type ( Appcompact Activity, ListActivity), Depend on the activity change theme for activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.No_Title_AppTheme);
}
```

In style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    </style>
    <style name="No_Title_AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">

    </style>
</resources>
```